# JSforce - how to get the running user?

Tags: javascript, jsforce

I'm following the [Getting Started](https://jsforce.github.io/start/#visualforce) section on the JSforce documentation and I'm getting the following error:

> resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
>   INVALID_SESSION_ID Session expired or
>   invalid

Code:

```
<apex:page >
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsforce/1.9.1/jsforce.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$API.Session_Id}' });
      conn.query('SELECT Id,Name FROM User WHERE Id=:Userinfo.getUserId()', function(err, res) {
        if (err) { return handleError(err); }
          console.log('works!');
          console.log(res);
      });        
   </script>
</apex:page>
```

I assume that the issue is related to 'Userinfo.getUserId()' because if I change the query to `SELECT Id,Name FROM User` then it works.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use UserInfo.getUserId() because you are running the code from Visualforce and not from apex. Instead, try with {!$User.Id}:

```
conn.query("SELECT Id,Name FROM User WHERE Id='{!$User.Id}'", function(err, res) {
    if (err) { return handleError(err); }
      console.log('works!');
      console.log(res);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you @Guillem Medina, where can I find this information documented?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm